# For Multivariate Gaussian Mixture Models, What will happen if all mixing probabilities are equal?

Tags: self-study, gaussian-mixture-distribution

$$p(\boldsymbol{x}) =\sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{\mu}_k, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_k) $$

This is the formula for [MGMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Multivariate_Gaussian_mixture_model), where $\pi_k$ is the mixing probability.

I am very curious about what is gonna happen if all mixing probabilities are equal. What is the algorithm now?

Comment: Maybe you should extend the question a little bit... the algorithm for doing what? You mean you want to figure out the parameters $\pi_k, \mu_k, \Sigma_k$ using the EM algo?

Comment: Why would something special happen?

Comment: @FabianWerner I included a link as to what this is. It is the PDF of a $K$ dimensional Gaussian mixture model. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @Carl: the question of the op was “what happens in the algorithm” and my question was: in what algorithm? Estimating the parameters, making a prediction, obtaining confidence bounds, ...?

Comment: @FabianWerner OP means equation, and equations imply procedures called algorithms. For example, division, is strictly speaking an algorithm.

Comment: @Carl: Not sure we are talking about the same thing here. I don't thing it makes sense to continue this discussion...

Comment: You need to clarify the use of the word "algorithm". If you mean "equation" say so. If you means something else, you then need to say what.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer to an imprecise question is that, if all mixing probabilities $\pi_k$ are equal, they all equal $1/K$ and hence do not need to be estimated. If one is using the EM algorithm this removes one term in the $M$-step. If one is using a Gibbs sampler for Bayesian estimation there is one less distribution to simulate from..

Comment: (+1) for nothing special. Note though that I do not think it is imprecise, just easy to misunderstand.